# How can I translate the private IP address of default gateway to public IP address in C#

Tags: c#, ip, nat, upnp

I wanna use the external IP address of gateway to recognize specific organization or group of machines because I think the gateway can be used as identifier of network address group. Obviously I can get the IP address of default gateway, but that IP address is written in private IP address.
On searching through web, I can get the web site echo the external IP address back to caller, but that doesn't allow me to input certain IP address.
In short, I want to know how to translate private IP address of gateway into external IP address. Specifically I want to know about the .NET libraries but it's okay to know any other libraries to get the desired result. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an external api like [ipify](https://www.ipify.org/) or [others](http://whatismyipaddress.com/api) to get your external api.

It's a simple get to server and you get your real ip in response.